# cannot use docker with proxy in win10

Tags: docker, docker-proxy

I want to use Docker in win10 with a proxy for that I use GUI to set a proxy in the settings, I add this:

```
   http://127.0.0.1:9090
```

but it won't work it always returns the same error

```
docker login
WARNING: Error loading config file: C:\Users\mk\.docker\config.json: invalid character '"' after object key:value pair
Authenticating with existing credentials...
Login did not succeed, error: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username (mohamadk): Password:
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

this is my config.json

```
{
  "stackOrchestrator": "swarm",
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
  },
  "credsStore": "wincred"

}
```

this is how I configure the docker
[image: add proxy to docker settings]

this is my proxy settings

[image: psiphone local proxy settings]

I'm using win10 Pro and Psiphon3 for proxy

Comment: Isn't this the reason: `WARNING: Error loading config file: C:\Users\mk\.docker\config.json: invalid character '"' after object key:value pair`?

Comment: no, unfortunately, that's not the case

Comment: Then I assume it's about the proxy configuration. This way or another you'll need to supply more information (config.json and proxy configuration - anonymized OFC, proxy logs).

Comment: I updated my question